# Install monitor application on maximo application suite in techzone environement

Tags: maximo, maximo-anywhere, ibm-maximo-worker-insights

I would like to install application monitor on MAS techzone knowing that I have installed application manage but I have no idea about installing the monitor application what I did is go to the catalog list and I chose monitor and I clicked on the deploy button but nothing works, it has still been running for 3 days
Is there a very detailed document to follow?

I would like to install application monitor on MAS techzone knowing that I have installed application manage but I have no idea about installing the monitor application what I did is go to the catalog list and I chose monitor and I clicked on the deploy button but nothing works, it has still been running for 3 days
Is there a very detailed document to follow?